# jQuery Content Slider Stopped working after Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

```
function nextSlideFunc() {
    var currentSlide = $(".slide.active-slide");
    var currentSlideIndex = $(".slide.active-slide").index();
    var nextSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex + 1;
    var nextSlide = $(".slide").eq(nextSlideIndex);

    $("#nextBtn").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        currentSlide.removeClass("active-slide");

        if(nextSlideIndex === $(".slide").last().index() + 1) {
            //stay at last slide when reached.
            $(".slide").eq(nextSlideIndex - 1).addClass("active-slide");
        } else {
            nextSlide.addClass("active-slide");
        }
    });

}
```

After I clicked on the next button, the slide goes to the next slide which is what I want, but when I continue to click, it just stopped going forward.

I checked my HTML in the dev tool, it has the class name "active-slide" on one of the slides which fulfills the condition, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

As for the previous button, it's not removing class "active-slide" like it's supposed to, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set your variables inside the listener of your click event:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxMxwd

```
$("#prevBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    var currentSlide = $(".slide.active-slide");
    var currentSlideIndex = $(".slide.active-slide").index();
    var prevSlideIndex = currentSlideIndex - 1;
    var prevSlide = $(".slide").eq(prevSlideIndex);
}
```

That way you will calculate your index and next index every time you click the button. The way you did it, is calculating it once and reusing it over and over again, so you will do the same thing on the same index over and over again.

Comment: I didn't realize the silly mistake! Thanks so much for clarifying :))